# open gmail compose window from javascript (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gmail

How can I open a gmail compose window (I don't care much which - popup/modal) with content I provide from Javascript? The context is a groceries app written in angular js where I want to add a button that will send the current list via email, but with the ability to edit it first (so not using GAS MailApp) 
In particular, the groceries list is large and can't be put as a URL parameter.

Answer (score 6):

you should open window with this link and parameters

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com&tf=1

**Params**

to:

su:

body:

bcc:

you can use $window.open with these parameters and provide your text as body

Comment: but i can't do this when the body is large (a groceries list), since the URL size is limited